# Return Scala object to C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, scala, java-native-interface

```
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
delete options;
if (rc != JNI_OK) {
    cin.get();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

cout << "JVM load succeeded: Version ";
jint ver = env->GetVersion();
cout << (((int) ver >> 16) & 0x0f) << "." << ((int)ver & 0x0f) << endl;
jclass thisClass = env->FindClass("Test");
cout << thisClass << endl;


jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(thisClass, "<init>", "()V");
cout << constructor << endl; 

jobject testObject = env->NewObject(thisClass, constructor);

jmethodID getExpression = env->GetMethodID(thisClass, "getExpression", "()Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;");
```

I'm trying to call a Scala function from C++ using JNI, return a Scala object to C++, and then translate (by hand) the returned object into a C++ object that I can pass to a native method.

I'm aware that there are a few hiccups when accessing Scala from C++ through JNI, but I'd appreciate a few pointers on how to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually you need to look through generated bytecode of compiled scala class to get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general advice is to inspect generated byte code before trying to deal with scala classes. Sometimes `scalac` may produce non-intuitive cumbersome bytecode. For example case class

```
case class CaseClass(value: Int)
```

will be compiled to something like (output is generated by [`procyon`](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon))

```
public class CaseClass {

    public static CaseClass apply(int p0) {
        return:CaseClass(invokevirtual:CaseClass(CaseClass$::apply, getstatic:CaseClass$(CaseClass$::MODULE$), p0:int))
    }

    public int value() {
        return:int(getfield:int(CaseClass::value, this:CaseClass))
    }

    // the rest is omitted
}
```

In that case in order to obtain `CaseClass` `value` you'll have to

```
jmethodID apply = env->GetStaticMethodID(thisClass, "apply", "(I)LCaseClass;");
jobject object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(thisClass, apply, 5);
jmethodID getValue = env->GetMethodID(thisClass, "value", "()I");
jint value = env->CallIntMethod(object, getValue);
```